# Dereference variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, pointers, variables, dereference

I have two variables. One variable gets set to the other, but I would like to assign the *value*, not the *pointer.* [According to Microsoft's Javascript Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/copying-passing-and-comparing-data-javascript#by-value-vs-by-reference), a variable, when assigned, is set to the same pointer of the source variable.

Here is a boiled-down version of my code:

```
var foo = { "baz": "qux" };
var bar = foo;
foo.baz = "quuz";
console.log(foo); // should equal {"baz": "quuz"}
console.log(bar); // should equal {"baz": "qux"}
```

Is there an easy, straightforward way to do this? If so, I can't find any documentation of it.

Comment: Copy the object. Quick, dirty and not optimized for performance: `var bar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo));` Search for shallow/deep cloning of JavaScript objects for alternatives.

Comment: Please use Object.assign instead.So you have to write var bar = Object.assign({},foo);This would serve the purpose.Please read through this:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: @Shadow Worth noting that `Object.assign()` will only create a shallow copy.

Comment: Wont that serve @yummypasta's purpose??